# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException error

Tags: ssl, service, apache-axis

In our application we use https service url to get some service from other vendor. we all share with one server. this server interacts with service url and gets the information.
 in all of other systems the service is able to be called successfully with successful requests and responses from server to service url.

in my system the following error is showing.

i think this is because of the my browser settings i need to do in order to invoke the request successfully..

can anybody suggest something on this..

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal cause is: 
        java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The certificate issued by

java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:346)
```

Comment: "The certificate issued by [...]". Obviously there is something missing here. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Truststore is not properly built. Please verify that your truststore has all the intermediate and root CA certs which have signed the server certificate.

Comment: i am using the same copy of the jboss server in my system.if it is working for my friend why it is not working for  me

Comment: This is a client side error. You are connecting to a server as a client and for the SSL handshake to complete your client has to have a truststore which contains the certificates of the trusted CAs which in your case is not valid. Check your SSL config parameters if you are missing or misconfigured something.

Comment: What evidence is present for this conclusion?

Comment: @EJP Check the stack trace. He is using the HTTPClient which is a client class.

Comment: my browser is having https and i am able to get the https without any problem..but when i call to web service this problem is coming...

Comment: you are correct...but the problem is that the jdk that i am pointing to...does not have valid trust store...so i changed that with working jdk...it is working....the problem is not with truststore...as i told you it was working for my friends but not to me...

Comment: Get the cacerts file from your working JDK and add it to the one which is not working under jre/lib/security. cacerts file is the truststore file. Check which certs are missing from the store.